# How to filter dataframe based on ip range

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, python-3.6, ip-address

I have dataframe which has 2 columns. I want to filter this dataframe based on ip ranges present in json file.

**ip_ranges.json**

```
[
    {"start": "45.43.144.0", "end": "45.43.161.255"}
    {"start": "104.222.130.0", "end": "104.222.191.255"}
    ...
]
```

**Dataframe:**

```
ip,p_value
97.98.173.96,3.7
73.83.192.21,6.9
...
```

Note: ip_range.json contains 100k elements and my dataframe has 300k rows.

Currently, I implemented like this

- Created python list to store all ips in each range. For example ["45.43.144.0", "45.43.144.1", "45.43.144.2", ..., "45.43.161.255"]. Similar way for all ip ranges.
- Removed duplicate elements from this list
- Constructed dataframe using this list
- Merged two dataframes on 'ip'

This process works fine for small set of ip_ranges. But for large set of ip_ranges, the process takes longer time to complete.

Is there any better approach to perform this more efficiently?

Comment: I'm not sure the final desired output, but for starters, do you want to check if each ip of `ip` column from your Dataframe is in any of ranges in `ip_ranges.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea: Put you ranges into a dataframe `ip_range` with columns `From` and `To`. Convert all ip-addresses (the ones in `df`, too) to decimal numbers with the fast code provided for example [here](https://gist.github.com/cslarsen/1595135).

Now generating the ranges can be done fast:

`ip_range['Rng'] = ip_range.apply(lambda x: np.arange(x.From, x.To+1), axis=1)`

These ranges can be converted into a DataFrame:

`ips = pd.DataFrame(itertools.chain(*ip_range['Rng']))`

This DataFrame can easily be merged with `df`.